# MySQL - Group Query Values in Same Table

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok, so I have a table with TaskID and ChildOf as fields... so ...

TaskID is Unique and Auto-Increment

```
If ChildOf == 0, then it has no Parent (top tier)...

If ChildOf != 0, then it is assigned TaskId of its Parent
```

Question:  How to form a query to give the results like this ...

```
Parent Task
 Child Task
 Child Task

Parent Task
 Child Task

Etc.. etc...
```

Would it be easier if I use two tables?  I'm going to have a lot of items in this table so I want to use as few queries (loops) as possible.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: is `TaskId` unique in this table?

Comment: Yes, it is the primary key - auto increment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is one way by which you have to just do soting without using join....

this is as follow -

```
select * from table_name order by decode(ChildOf,0,TaskID,ChildOf),ChildOf
```

this will give desired output...

means parent node and then respective child node...
and then second parent node and so on..

one thing I don't know whether docode function runs on my sql as well or not..

if not then you can use following query -

```
select * from table_name order by case when ChildOf=0 then TaskID else ChildOf end,ChildOf
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.   Works great!  Thank you!  However, A task of a task that ChildOf != 0, still does not work... Any way to make that work?

Comment: BTW it was the second query you gave that worked, the first one produced an error in mysql.  (missing parameter for decode)

Comment: about decode function in mysql ... i told in my post that i don't have any knowledge in mysql .... so sorry .. this time you have to google for this and corresponding function...

as per your question parent node is having 0 value in childof column so thats why i wrote this kind of query ..but if you have different value for this situation .. say NULL value then just change this case statement and put that value (NULL) in place of '0'

Comment: childof != 0 .... do you mean by child node???/

it should work ....

please comment what kind of output you are getting ...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using recursion for this.  Check out http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database/ for a good breakdown on how to do this.

If you are against using recursion, then you can look at using a left and a right value to determine where the and using a tree traversal algorithm to retrieve your data.

Just let me know if you do not want to use recursion and I can explain how to do it the other ways ( they are a lot more complex and I did not want to type it out if you were just going to use recursion because it would take about an hour or so to type out!! )

Comment: Interesting quote from your referenced article: "We need one database query for each node in the tree." Does that sound like a tolerable situation to you?

Comment: No, I did not think it was tolerable, which is why I decided to use a different, more complicated way to store the data.  It involved storing a left and a right value for all entries.  This will give you a way to pull the data, and then order it by the left and right values, giving you a tree structure. It is complex and you need to write a lot of custom code. This meant less connections to the database, and we have a slow connection, so this method was the way we chose to go. Check out http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/ for a good description. Let me know if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on how your sample output is formatted, it seems like you only have two levels of hierarchy, i.e. every item is either a parent or a child.

If that is so, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM atable t
  LEFT JOIN atable p ON t.ChildOf = p.TaskId
ORDER BY
  COALESCE(p.TaskId, t.TaskId),
  CASE WHEN p.TaskId IS NOT NULL THEN t.TaskId ELSE 0 END
```

This will group parents together with their children, sorting the former before the latter.